# overwrite dll in build output using csproj

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22781) with System.Net.Http.

Visual Studio 2017 will take the `System.Net.Http.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib` and put it in the build output. On my machine, this is version 4.3.4 (file version 4.6.26011.1)

If you use a `<PackageReference>` or even a direct `<Reference>` to a different version of `System.Net.Http.dll`, Visual Studio 2017 will disregard your version in favor of its version when creating the build output (in the /bin folder).

This will lead to errors when you try to call the dll externally.

**Main Question:**

Is there any way to force msbuild/csproj to use the version I reference from NuGet?
Maybe, can I copy and overwrite the existing System.Net.Http.dll in a post-build action?

**What I have tried:**

I tried using a binding redirect, but that doesn't seem to affect the build output at all ([see this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22781#issuecomment-322694600)).

Comment: "There is a known issue" is a big mistake for your question context. There are in fact tons of them and each caused by different factors and with different solutions. So in your case, you need to follow what @joperezr suggested in that thread to open a new issue on GitHub with a sample project to reproduce the issue. That also applies to Stack Overflow, as none of us can see your code. BTW, I don't see why a post-build action would not help.

Comment: @LexLi Sure, but my main question remains regardless of the specific case. Anyways, I figured out how to use a post-build action to copy and overwrite the correct version of the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but this works for me:

1. Find the correct version of System.Net.Http.dll and then place it
   somewhere accessible to your project (like in a /libs folder under
   your root project folder)
2. Using an msbuild/csproj post-build action, copy the correct version to the build output

---

.csproj snippet for step 2:

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="libs\System.Net.Http.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

---

**Note:**

Supposedly, [this will be fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/dotnet472-changes.md) in net472